# Is it possible to set the selected option if the option list is in a partial view?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC Core 2.1 and I have a set of hard coded HTML options that I would like to re-use by placing them in a partial view. The page renders as desired but the selected option is not set.

This works:

```
<select asp-for="Person.Prefix" class="form-control">
    <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
    <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
    <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
    <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
</select>
```

This does not:

```
<select asp-for="Person.Prefix" class="form-control">
    <partial name="People/_PrefixOptions" />
</select>
```

where the contents of _PrefixOptions is

```
<option value="Miss">Miss</option>
<option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
<option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
<option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
```

I can't pull the entire select element into the partial because it is bound to different properties on other pages.

Comment: Why you don't use View Component instead of partial? View Components are the best solutions for hard coded html part.

Comment: I use view components for reusable menus, etc. They're far too complex for this simple use case where I just need to insert a chunk of HTML. The partial renders correctly, it's just that model binding doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `<partial>` Tag Helper you can pass data along in two ways:

- Use the `model` attribute to provide a model instance.

example, when you'd want to pass the `Model.Person` model along:

```
<select asp-for="Person.Prefix" class="form-control">
    <partial name="People/_PrefixOptions" model="Model.Person" />
</select>
```

- The `for` attribute allows you to pass a property of the current model inside the partial view.

example, when you'd want to pass the `Prefix` of model propert `Person` along:

```
<select asp-for="Person.Prefix" class="form-control">
    <partial name="People/_PrefixOptions" for="Person.Prefix" />
</select>
```

Note the absence of `Model.` when using the `for` attribute.

More information about the `<partial>` Tag Helper can be [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

#### Alternative

When using this functionality to mark a selected `<option>` element, it would still leave you with some work inside the partial. Personally I prefer to hardcode my options in a `SelectListItem` container and use the `asp-items` approach for select lists, [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.1#the-select-tag-helper).